# How to run tests on android emulator without loading the emulator everytime?

Tags: java, android, selenium, testing, appium

How to run tests on Android emulator without loading the emulator everytime when I running tests?

I have the code:

```
void prepareAndroidEmulator() throws MalformedURLException {
        File appDir = new File("/Users/oleh/Google Drive/QA DRIVE/Applications/some/sprint 2");
        File app = new File(appDir, BUILD_NAME);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("avd", "LG_G4._API_22._Android_5.1");

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "AndroidTestDevice");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
      @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        prepareAndroidEmulator();

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill");
    }
```

I kill emulator specially because if I don't do it, next time I have an error or ide is skipping tests.

[Screen about skipped tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNItS.png)

Main idea: I don't want to load and kill emulator everytime when I starting tests. I want to load emulator once and after use it all time, when I running test.

My environment:

-OS X El Capitan
-Intellij IDEA
-Selenium
-Appium

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of a test suite that exhibits the "skipped tests" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `noReset=true` and `fullReset= false` capability before starting the Appium server.

Comment: It doesn't help me. I added capabilities and now I have an error when I run tests, they are ignored. 

Test ignored.
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

Comment: My code now is:
`@BeforeClass
        DesiredCapabilities c = new DesiredCapabilities();
        c.setCapability("avd", "LG_G4._API_22._Android_5.1");
        c.setCapability("deviceName", "AndroidTestDevice");
        c.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        c.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        c.setCapability("fullReset", "False");
        c.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`